# reeact - load api data into this.state for text use

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to understand why my Text is not rendering please and how i can get this working

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View,Button,Text } from 'react-native';

export default class LiveApiData extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {data:[]}
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("<<taking out the api key")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(new_data => {this.setState({data:new_data})})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ height: 200, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <Text> {this.state.data[0]}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Much appreciated in advance

Comment: Your text is not rendering cause your View is mounted **before** the promise is resolved.

Comment: @GaëtanBoyals oh ok thank you, how do i repair the situation?

Comment: Actually, I might have said the wrong thing. Since you're using promises and setting a state when it's resolved, it **should** trigger a re-render, causing your text to appear. Are you sure the promise is resolved? I'd also advise to add the catch method on your promise to handle such cases

Comment: console.log the response first and then check on which property the data is on the response object and then pass that property to the setState call.

Comment: @MontyTomar when i console.log the response it shows data.

Comment: Could you copy paste the response object here.

Comment: try consoling the **new_data** in second then statement and put the results of console in the comments.

Comment: @MontyTomar > result of console.log for the .then(new_data >>>

0:{timestamp:"2018-04-14T00:00:00Z",rate:"7999.09816231845214650049179249741253"}
►1:{timestamp:"2018-04-15T00:00:00Z",rate:"8357.6586830697213301743207363910892"}
►2:{timestamp:"2018-04-16T00:00:00Z",rate:"8046.07792934854261706414967686716349"}
►3:{timestamp:"2018-04-17T00:00:00Z",rate:"7893.45243140321004304169688047137288"}

Comment: Try consoling your state object right before the return method in render method to check whether the state is updated or not with the data you're fetching.

Comment: @MontyTomar yep i did it before the return statement is see the data

Comment: Since it's an array of **objects**, try swaping `{this.state.data[0]}` to `{this.state.data[0].timestamp}`

Answer (score 0):

In the above code in the render() you are rendering the data which is an array so. If this array is a collection of objects you will need to specify the key name to render the text. If the array is of strings then it should get rendered.

I am pasting a working example for this question.[Example Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-rosalind-yr4rj)

The solution will add a null check. Because the state will be empty when you are rendering at the first time.

```
<div style={{ height: 200, flexDirection: "row" }}>
    <div> {this.state.data.length ? this.state.data[0].title : ""}. </div>
</div>
```